# Driver is a process or not?

Tags: process, operating-system, driver

Working driver is a process of OS or not? Wiki says „Process is an instance of a computer program that is being executed“, but dll is not a process. In other side, driver have virtual memory, stack and so on like a process, but for opening we use `CreateFile`/`fopen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no.  Drivers, (at least partially), don't have a process context because they are given execution by hardware interrupts that transfer execution from currently running processes.

Multi-level drivers can, and do, have threads/processes as support, but the lowest levels cannot be considered processes/threads.

Comment: How OS calls driver's functions without context? And what if driver want execute system call (get memory, for example)?

Comment: 'How OS calls driver's functions without context?'  The lowest levels of drivers are not always called by the OS, they are interrupted-to by hardware.  'what if driver want execute system call, get memory, for example)?' - at the lowest levels, many syscalls are just not available.  Trying to call them will blow up the OS.